# Uso de jQuery en prestashop

Tags: prestashop, cms

Intentando usar jQuery en mi tema, me encuentro con que al ir a usarlo con el código siguiente:

`$(document).ready(function(){
// aqui mi codigo.....
});`

Me saca el error de que '$' no está definido, como si jQuery no estuviese cargado. Veo en consola que automáticamente Prestashop carga jquery-ui pero no jquery "normal". Le añado la librería pero ya empieza a sacarme más fallos (intuyo que propios de prestashop porque use jquery de forma interna).

¿Cómo puedo trabajar con jquery en prestashop entonces? Añado en javascript.tpl el fichero jquery pero me da los problemas que veis más arriba.

Comment: Qué tal si cargas la librería internamente y utilizas jQuery.noConflict();
Lo guardas en una variable y las acciones jQuery las utilizas con esa variable del siguiente modo:
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){ });

O sea, en vez de usar $, usa j

Comment: Es lo que he hecho @user2930137 pero al usarlo me dice que la función que intento usar no es una función (el código es simplemente esto: `<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
  j(".products").isotope();
});
</script>` y me dice que isotope no es una función

Comment: El error te lo maca en el ready o en el uso de isotope?

Comment: Me da con .isotope cuando está cargado y demás...estoy buscando en el código y resulta que prestashop usa el mismo bloque de clase "products" para mostrar el carrito y los productos...quizás esté encontrandome los 2 y por eso falle¿?

Comment: Puede ser, intenta cambiarle el nombre de la clase o agregale una clase extra y haz la acción por medio de esa clase y no products.

Comment: He intentado meterlo en otra clase incluso y nada, sigue sacando lo mismo...lo ponga en una clase mía inventada, en una de un bloque de prestashop...me resulta muy raro. Lo meto (jquery e isotope) en la ruta `mitema/assets/js`y el codigo javascript en `mitema/templates/_partials/javascript.tpl` son esos los sitios correctos no?

Answer (score 1):

La solución:

El problema estaba en que la librería de jQuery se estaba cargando **justo después de cargar la de isotope.js** por eso no me reconocía lo que tenía la librería.

Una vez cambiado el orden de carga (1º jQuery - 2º isotope) ya funciona todo perfectamente. ;)

Comment: recuerda aceptar tu propia respuesta si es lo que funciono!